# How to read SSTables

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-cli

I am newbie to cassandra and want to read SSTables generated from incremental backups what are the ways to read SSTables.Tried open source tool hadoop-sstable mention in this [link](https://github.com/fullcontact/hadoop-sstable) but it only support cassandra-1 and not cassandra 2.0.What are the different way to read Cassandra SSTable.

Comment: Take a look at sstable2json, it outputs the sstable in JSON format.

Comment: sstable2json outputs in json format but its output is different for Primary key and composite keys and also for deletion for e.g:            [
{"key": "00000004","metadata": {"deletionInfo": {"markedForDeleteAt":14113661171
79000,"localDeletionTime":1411366117}},"columns": []}
]


[
{"key": "00000005","columns": [["2","2:!",1411366556988000,"t",1411366556]]}
]